# Retrieve the Salesforce Org-wide API Consumption Percentage?

Tags: rest-api, api, limits

I have been googling this for a while, the closest I have come to getting an answer on this is the API Consumption report [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gtGmAAI)

However, I am looking to retrieve the current SFDC Org-wide API consumption metric via the Salesforce *API* itself.

Is there an Endpoint I can call to get this data?

Use case: I have several scripts running on a schedule that move large amounts of Data around on Salesforce, which risks our SFDC org getting capped out and I would like to check the API Consumption percentage for last 24 hours, and if the Consumption percentage is over a certain amount, the script does not proceed through the rest of the sequence.

This should help us avoid hitting our allotted max of API calls.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely certain if this is what you are seeking, but there is a "Limits" resource available through the REST API (I think introduced in 2015 or 16).

You can review documentation about this resource here:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce REST API offers a [Limits REST Endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm?search_text=limits) which provides the ability to retrieve the org-wide API consumption. This is available in API version 29.0 and later.

The sample REST endpoint for retrieving your org API consumption is as below

```
https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/limits
```

Additionally, refer my blog on [Stalking Your Salesforce Governor Limits Was Never This Easy](https://learnsfdcwithjigar.wordpress.com/2017/10/14/stalking-your-salesforce-governor-limits-was-never-this-easy/) to understand more about the request and response format to retrieve your org limit consumption.

**In addition to providing details of API limit consumption it also provides details around the following limits**

> - Daily asynchronous Apex method executions (batch Apex, future    methods, queueable Apex, and scheduled Apex)
> - Daily Bulk API calls
> - Daily Streaming API events (API version 36.0 and earlier)
> - Daily durable Streaming API events (API version 37.0 and later)
> - Streaming API concurrent clients (API version 36.0 and earlier)
> - Durable Streaming API concurrent clients (API version 37.0 and later)
> - Daily generic streaming events (API version 36.0 and earlier)
> - Daily durable generic streaming events (API version 37.0 and later)
> - Daily number of mass emails that are sent to external email addresses    by using Apex or APIs
> - Daily number of single emails that are sent to external email addresses by using Apex or APIs
> - Concurrent REST API requests for results of asynchronous report runs
> - Concurrent synchronous report runs via REST API
> - Hourly asynchronous report runs via REST API
> - Hourly synchronous report runs via REST API
> - Hourly dashboard refreshes via REST API
> - Hourly REST API requests for dashboard results
> - Hourly dashboard status requests via REST API
> - Daily workflow emails
> - Hourly workflow time triggers
> - Hourly OData callouts
> - Daily and active scratch org counts